# Error: network does not support ENS (operation=“ENS”, network=“maticmum”, code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=providers/5.5.3 Network doesnot support

Tags: ethereum, solidity, networkx, web3js, unsupportedoperation

Hello I wrote  a smart contract for crowd funding
Actually I have two contracts One is create a campaign for donate funds and second is created campigns for crowd-funding and store all the campaigns address in one place when the user will create the campaign.
Now When I try to pass the stored campaign addresses as an endpoints in params in getStaticPaths.To filter the data in next js this error is coming
`Error: network does not support ENS (operation=“ENS”, network=“maticmum”, code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=providers/5.5.3 Network doesnot support` 
can anybody tell me why this error is coming?

Here is my Smart Contracts Code

```
pragma solidity >0.8.0;
    contract campaignFactory{

Here is my address stored

    address [] public deployedCampaigns;
    event createdCampaign(
        address indexed owner,
        string indexed category, 
        uint indexed timestamp,
        string title, 
        string storyUrI,
        uint requireAmount,
        string imageUrI,
        address campaignAddress
        );
    function createCampaign(
        string memory title,
        string memory storyUrI,
        uint requireAmount,
        string memory category,
        string memory imageUrI
    )public{
    Campaign newCampaign=new Campaign(title,storyUrI,requireAmount,msg.sender,imageUrI);
    deployedCampaigns.push(address(newCampaign));
    emit createdCampaign(msg.sender, category, block.timestamp, title, storyUrI, requireAmount, imageUrI,address(newCampaign));
    }
    this is my other smart contract to creat campaigns and donate function to send amount to owner who deployed campaigns.
    
    contract Campaign{
    event donated(address indexed owner,uint indexed amount,uint indexed timestamp);
    string public campaignTitle;
    string public story;
    uint public requireAmount;
    uint public receivedAmount;
    address payable public campaignOwner;
    string public image;
    constructor(
        string memory _campaignTitle,
        string memory _story,
        uint _requireAmount,
        address _owner,
        string memory _image
    ){
     campaignTitle=_campaignTitle;
            story=_story;
            requireAmount=_requireAmount;
            campaignOwner=payable(_owner);
            image=_image;
    }
    function donate()payable public{
    require(requireAmount>receivedAmount,"Require Amount is fullfilled");
    campaignOwner.transfer(msg.value);
    receivedAmount+=msg.value;
    emit donated(msg.sender, msg.value, block.timestamp);
    }
    }
```

Here is my Next Js Code

````
    export async function getStaticPaths(){
    const provider=new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(
        AlchemyProvider
    );
    const contract=new ethers.Contract(
    contractAddress,
    CampaignFactory.abi,
    provider
    )
    const getAllCampaigns=contract.filters.createdCampaign();
    const allCampaigns=await contract.queryFilter(getAllCampaigns);
    return{
    paths:allCampaigns.map((e)=>({
    params:{```
    **The Problem is coming here**
    **address:e.args.campaignAddress.toString()**
    }
    })),
    fallback:true
    }
    };
````

Comment: Please don't write everything in bold, and format your code properly, if you want anybody to read it.

Comment: Please your request isnt very clear, state exactly what you want the community to help you with, am not very sure if your requesting from the community how to write a smart contract in solidity, if thats the case, i think thats the use of the solidity documentation, here with we help you sort out issues with your code an if your stuck with a challenge.
Also please use the input formatters the input box provides you, it helps others easily understand your code and contribute to your challenge.
I will be providing links to some resources on how to write smart contracts , hope it helps, if you do

Comment: Probably best to ask at [Ethereum.se]

Answer (score 0):

if you calling function and your function require blackchin address but you pass wrong blockchain address than is error get

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).